# USB errors when interacting with device

Tags: fedora, usb

I have a USB device which plugs into my fedora 27 x64 system.  It is detected fine, but once my software starts to communicate with the device the dmesg log fills with:

```
[212972.138684] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.140176] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.141657] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.143166] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.144624] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.146152] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.147663] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
[212972.149142] usb 2-2.2: input irq status -75 received
```

What does status -75 mean?  And how would I fix this?  The log appears to be filling with hundreds of these messages per minute (or more)

Comment: Upgrade your kernel or file a bug.

Comment: What does -75 status mean?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine, but if you google USB errors, you'd come across many similar cases resolved through a kernel upgrade or a bug report lucky enough to get attention.

Comment: I have googled, and can't find any posts with -75 error, that's why I posted on stackexchange :)

Comment: I have googled, and can't find any posts with -75 error, that's why I posted on stackexchange :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is one of the [standard kernel error codes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h), which are negative by convention, `-75` is `EOVERFLOW` ("Value too large for defined data type").

This looks like a bug (possibly someone used an integer type somewhere that has not enough bits to hold the value), so file a bug report on the kernel debug tracker. Add enough information to reproduce the problem, i.e. the exact vendor/device id as given by `lsusb`, the complete `dmesg` output with all information that is given after you plug the device in, under which circumstances the message appears, etc.

If you know how to, recompile your kernel and enable USB debugging, so one can narrow down where the error comes from. Otherwise there's probably too much guessing involved to be able to find it.